# C++ file stream, copy data from .dat file to vector

Tags: c++, file, loops, vector, stream

I have a .dat file containing full of integers 100 by 100, and I am trying to transfer x rows and x columns into a new vector, I've managed to ge the first row with the desired columns but stuck in trying to get to the next line and until to the x rows, please give help. This is my code so far
also some help on the display part, I'm not sure how to display a vector with more than one rows and columns. Tried `data.at(i).at(j)` double for loop but unsuccessful

```
    //variable
int row, col;
string fname;
ifstream file;
vector<int> data;

//input
cout << "Enter the number of rows in the map: ";    cin >> row;
cout << "Enter the number of columns in the map: "; cin >> col;
cout << "Enter the file name to write: ";           cin >> fname;

//open file
file.open(fname, ios::in);  //  map-input-100-100.dat

int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
{
    file >> temp;
    data.push_back(temp);
}
// display first row of data
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) cout << data.at(i) << ' ';
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code could be like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> data; // instead of your definition of data:access data[r][c]

for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
{ 
    vector<int> x(column);        
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
    {
        file >> temp;
        x[i] = temp;
    }
    data.push_back(x);
}
```